# simple word choice ,unabridged or unedited version

Tags: word-choice

I don't know I whether I need to use *unabridged version* or *unedited version* for a radio podcast. Please explain the difference.

Also, is "said" the right word in the clause below?

"As he **said** in unabridged/unedited edition,...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a distinct difference between the two words. All abridged editions are edited because they've been shortened, which is what *abridged* means. However, not all unabridged editions are necessarily *unedited*. Sometimes an editor adds words, and sometimes an editor subtracts words. To edit something is merely to change it in some way, not necessarily to shorten it.

ANSWER: Therefore, if you are referring to the original published version, the one that hasn't been shortened, you must use *the unabridged edition* [You need the definite article "the"]. If you are referring to the author's original **and** unedited manuscript, you can refer to *the unedited manuscript* but not the *unedited edition* (using *edition* implies that it was published, but unedited work is **usually** not published commercially). "**Said**" is fine; you don't need to say **wrote**.